# angular-bootstrap-ui modal size doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

howto resize angular ui bootstrap modal on large size it looks that it doesn't work ? by the doc page it's enough to add size attribute https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal/docs , also when I try to add size='lg' (with ui-bootstrap version 0.10.0) into example.js open function in plunker from official page it doesn't work http://plnkr.co/edit/lNqi9T8HRUHzcleY68KB?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It "doesn't work" since the commit where this feature was introduced (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/976f6083e8485333612b05c023a3c490404543f0) wasn't released yet, so it is not part of the official 0.10.0 release.

You need to wait for 0.11.0 release (hopefully this weekend) or build your own version from the `master` branch as described here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#development

Comment: Well... that would certainly explain that!

Answer (score 9):

I've never had luck with that feature. We just add a class to the modal with the windowClass property and it all works.

```
CSS
.full .modal-dialog{
    width:auto;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
}

$modal.open({
   template:'blah.htm',
   windowClass:'full'
   controller:'blahCntrl'
});
```